# Can't write a long text in the table environment after Merge?

Tags: tables, multirow

I try to write LaTeX code similar to the following picture:
[image: FOMJ]

I cannot write a long text in the table environment after Merge.
My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htb]
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.45\textwidth}p{0.5\textwidth}}
            \hline
            A R T I C L E I N F O & A B S T R A C T\\  \cline{1-1}
            Article history: &  \multirow{1}{0.5\textwidth}{\justifying This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text} \\
            Received 1 May 2018 & \\
            Revised 26 July 2018 & \\
            Accepted 25 August 2018 & \\
            Available online 20 September 2018 & \\
            & \\ \cline{1-1}
            Keywords: & \\
            Bi-level linear programming & \\
            Fuzzy programming & \\
            TOPSIS\\
            Compromise solution & \\
            & \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: This is because the contents of your `\multirow` command take up more vertical space than the corresponding rows on the left. Also the number in the first argument of multirow is not correct. To overcome this, you could add some empty rows in the table. Personally, I wouldn't use a `tabular` for this but rather go for minipages instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, here is a solution using minpages:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
   \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
            A R T I C L E I N F O \\  
            \midrule
            Article history:  \\
            Received 1 May 2018 \\
            Revised 26 July 2018  \\
            Accepted 25 August 2018 \\
            Available online 20 September 2018  \\
            \midrule
            Keywords:  \\
            Bi-level linear programming  \\
            Fuzzy programming  \\
            TOPSIS\\
            Compromise solution  \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    A B S T R A C T 

    This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text
    \end{minipage}
   \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an MWE where I use nested tabulars to achieve the effect. The text is set flush with the margins, and using booktabs to get a better spacing. Also, I suggest using microtype to have letterspacing. If you prefer the indented text, just change the line

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.0em}
```

to

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5em}
```

You then need to extend the rule between the two text block (above "Keyword:") with one `\tabcolsep`, *i.e*.:

```
\\ \cmidrule(l{-\tabcolsep}){1-1}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

% Multi-line left-aligned text with manual line breaks.
% The base line of the whole is at the top row.
\newcommand*{\tstack}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.0em}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htb]
        \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{0.45\textwidth}p{0.5\textwidth}}
            \toprule
            \lsstyle ARTICLE INFO & \lsstyle ABSTACT\\  \cmidrule{1-1}
            \tstack{\emph{Article history}:\\
            Received 1 May 2018  \\
          Revised 26 July 2018  \\
            Accepted 25 August 2018  \\
            Available online 20 September 2018  \\
            \\ \cmidrule{1-1}
            \emph{Keywords}:  \\
            Bi-level linear programming  \\
            Fuzzy programming  \\
            \textls{\textsc{topsis}}\\
            Compromise solution  \\            
            } &  
            This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text  
\\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```